# How to get the directed line graph of the complete digraph?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

When we replace every edge of the complete graph $K_N$ by a pair of directed edges, we get a complete directed graph, the [Complete DiGraph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteDigraph.html) $DK_N$ .
Let $DL_{N}$ be directed line graph of the complete digraph.

> How to get the adjacency matrix $L$ of $DL_N$?

My attempt:

I setup a $N\times N$ matrix, like follows (e.g. $N=4$):
$$
\mathcal I=\pmatrix{
0&(0,1)&(0,2)&(0,3)\\
(1,0)&0&(1,2)&(1,3)\\
(2,0)&(2,1)&0&(2,3)\\
(3,0)&(3,1)&(3,2)&0
}
$$
so $\mathcal I$ is something like an index matrix, with $\mathcal I_{x,y}=(x,y)$. Then 
$$
L_{a,b}=\mathcal \delta_{y_ax_b},
$$
with $a=x_aN+y_a$ and $b=x_bN+y_b$. Where $\delta_{y_ax_b}$ means that we choose two non-diagonal elements of $\mathcal I$, namely $\mathcal I_{x_a,y_a}$ and $\mathcal I_{x_b,y_b}$. This is not symmetric because ingoing edges are only linked to outgoing ones.

Is this correct? Are there other ways to get $L$?

Comment: It is not clear to me what does "directed line graph of the complete digraph" means, could you please explain it a little bit?

Comment: @M.Badaoui you can boil it down to: Given the adjacency matrix of the complete digraph, how to you construct the adjacency matrix of the directed line graph.

Comment: Can't you just index the matrix $L$ by the pairs of vertices, in which case you just have $L_{(x,y)(s,t)}$ is $1$ iff $y=s$?

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure to understand what your question is, but this would be too long for a comment, so I will update this in case it's a blatant misunderstanding.

The directed line graph matrix of a complete directed graph has $N^2$ entries. 
Let $r = (a-N) \mod (N-1)$ and  $k = (a-N) / (N-1)$ (using integer division).
Then we can write (indices start at $0$):
$$L_{a,b} =  \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{if } a < N \text{ and } N+ a(N-1) \leq b < N+ (a+1)(N-1)\\
    1 & \text{if } a \geq N \text{ and } b < n  \text{ and } ( (r<k \text{ and } b=r) \text{ or } (r \geq k \text{ and } b=r+1)) \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Any permutation on the vertices would also do, but this seems to be the most natural one (and is already quite a horrible expression).

To get this to work for a general (weigthed, directed) graph  you can replace $1$ by the relevant $\mathcal I$ coefficient.

Comment: Thanks for your time not really what I was looking for but since you were the only one participating you'll get the bounty...

Comment: @draks... Oh hell, I understand now, I understood "line graph" as incidence graph, hence the confusion... I'll look soon at your proper question, sorry about that.